# app engine data store retrieving the deleted entities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am trying to delete all the entities of a kind. After deleting i am trying to make query on the same kind. But the thing is, even after deleting all the entities the query is giving the results with some 'n' number of rows. I know it is the HRD issue where the indexes are not deleted yet. But i want to know from where the query is getting the data though we are deleted the actual data.

Consider the below code,

```
class CustomReportInfo {
  String reportName;

 // Setter and getters
}
```

Here i am trying delete the CustomReportInfo kind entities. In order delete the entities what i am doing is,

```
List<CustomReportInfo> customReportInfoList = query(CustomReportInfo.class).list();
delete(customReportInfoList);
```

So, as you see i am deleting all the entities of CustomReportInfo. After that i am trying to make query on the same kind. Like,

```
List<CustomReportInfo> list = query(CustomReportInfo.class).list();
```

Still i am getting the 'n' number of rows after deleting. From where the query is getting the results even after the deleting the actual data?

Answer (score 0):

Eventual consistency in Cloud Datastore means that if you run a global query (like the one in your example), it may return results that have already been deleted.

To ensure that the deleted entities don't appear in query results, you could restructure your entities to user ancestors. There's an overview of some of these issues in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore).